# XSD to XML with imports

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, standards, invoices

I'm currently developing a service for generating XML files which follows the UBL standard for an invoice, and therefore I need to use some provided XSD schemas.

I'm developing in .NET C#, and found a way where you can map the XSD to C# classes - by using the XSD.exe - which seems OK?

The problem that I'm facing is, that there are other namespaces in xsd file, which seems to make some problems for my generated classes (xsd:imports):

```
<!-- ===== xsd:schema Element With Namespaces Declarations ===== -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
version="2.0">
<!-- ===== Imports ===== -->
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" schemaLocation="../common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd"/>
<!-- ===== Root Element ===== -->
<xsd:element name="Invoice" type="InvoiceType">
...
```

I ran the xsd.exe with the following command:

```
xsd.exe /c C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\maindoc\UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\CodeList_UnitCode_UNECE_7_04.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\CodeList_MIMEMediaTypeCode_IANA_7_04.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\CodeList_LanguageCode_ISO_7_04.xsd C:\Users\tn\Downloads\os-UBL-2.0\os-UBL-2.0\xsd\common\CodeList_CurrencyCode_ISO_7_04.xsd
```

When I try to make the XML file with use of the generated code, the output looks like this, where the imports and namespacepreceders is missing, and it ends up failing the validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
   <UBLVersionID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">2.0</UBLVersionID>
   <LegalMonetaryTotal xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
   <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="DKK" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">200</LineExtensionAmount>
   <PayableAmount currencyID="DKK" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">300</PayableAmount>
   </LegalMonetaryTotal>
</Invoice>
```

And here som samplecode where I generate the XML from the generated classes via a xmlserializer

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InvoiceType));
    InvoiceType invoice = new InvoiceType();

    UBLVersionIDType UVer = new UBLVersionIDType();
    UVer.Value = "2.0";
    invoice.UBLVersionID = UVer;

    MonetaryTotalType mtt = new MonetaryTotalType();
    LineExtensionAmountType lep = new LineExtensionAmountType();
    lep.currencyID = CurrencyCodeContentType.DKK;
    lep.Value = 200;
    PayableAmountType pat = new PayableAmountType();
    pat.currencyID = CurrencyCodeContentType.DKK;
    pat.Value = 300;

    mtt.LineExtensionAmount = lep;
    mtt.PayableAmount = pat;

    invoice.LegalMonetaryTotal = mtt;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\New folder\test2.xml");

    mySerializer.Serialize(sw, invoice);
    sw.Close();
```

How can I fix this, and is this the right (best/easiest( way to make XMLs which follows xsd schemas in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out myself.

Needed the XmlSerializerNamespaces-object which contains the namespaces and prefixes for the XML-document.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx)

Comment: how did you do to get the cbc: etc namespace preceders to appear.. Did you have to modify the outputted c# classes from the UBL XSD? Or was it just something different when serializing...

Comment: @JamesReategui did you find an answer to your question?